# web API- Multiform data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

[Passing 2 form data]I have to pass form data in key value pair in a `WebApi`.I have 2 data
`Key,value`
fwdp        `{"abc":"dfgg","ijk":"opik"}`
d_details   `{"klj":"hjj","hk":"tyush"}`
Please suggest me , as I have seen only passing file in multiform data, how can we pass this dynamic generated `Json` to form data through c# code.
Is there any other option to send multi forma data.

Comment: why do you prefer the multi-part form data, this does not involve any file inputs?

Comment: I have WebApi URL and i have to pass two key , value pair values under  formdata in body part through c# code. Can you suggest how can i achieve this. i heard about multi form data so i tried.

Comment: try this
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17449/Send-a-content-type-multipart-form-data-request-fr